# SOA Composite XSLT Transformation

Tags: xslt-2.0, soa

```
Sample input data

interfaceSourceCode,requisitioningBUName,InterfaceHeaderKey,CategoryName,CurrencyCode,DeliverToLocationCode,DeliverToOrganizationCode,DestinationTypeCode,InterfaceLineKey,ItemDescription,ItemNumber,LineType,NoteToBuyer,ProcurementBUName,Quantity,RequesterEmail,UnitOfMeasureCode,Price,ChargeAccountSegment1,ChargeAccountSegment2,ChargeAccountSegment3,ChargeAccountSegment4,ChargeAccountSegment5,ChargeAccountSegment6,ChargeAccountSegment7,DistributionQuantity,InterfaceDistributionKey,Percent
SCO,XXXX Internal Customer Service - CA,300000039139651,"Chemicals, Lubricants and Non-Gen Fuels.Additives.Additives",CAD,Nisku Distribution Centre,NDC,INVENTORY,400000039139652,"TRANSFORMER, 25 KVA OH, 12470GRDY/7200/347/600Y 1PH C/W TAPS SPEC. #YECL-T-15",16340094,Goods,TEST12345678,XXXX Internal Customer Service - CA,6,xyz@discard.mail.us2.oracle.cloud.com,zzr,500,10002,00000,00000,00000,130000,00000,00,6,500000039139652,100
SCO,XXXX Internal Customer Service - CA,300000039139651,"Chemicals, Lubricants and Non-Gen Fuels.Additives.Additives",CAD,Nisku Distribution Centre,NDC,INVENTORY,400000039139653,"TRANSFORMER, 25 KVA OH, 12470GRDY/7200/347/600Y 1PH C/W TAPS SPEC. #YECL-T-15",16340094,Goods,TEST12345678,XXXX Internal Customer Service - CA,6,xyz@discard.mail.us2.oracle.cloud.com,zzr,500,10002,00000,00000,00000,130000,00000,00,6,500000039139653,100
SCO,XXXX Internal Customer Service - CA,300000039139652,"Chemicals, Lubricants and Non-Gen Fuels.Additives.Additives",CAD,Nisku Distribution Centre,NDC,INVENTORY,400000039139654,"TRANSFORMER, 25 KVA OH, 12470GRDY/7200/347/600Y 1PH C/W TAPS SPEC. #YECL-T-15",16340094,Goods,TEST12345678,XXXX Internal Customer Service - CA,6,xyz@discard.mail.us2.oracle.cloud.com,zzr,500,10002,00000,00000,00000,130000,00000,00,6,500000039139654,100
SCO,XXXX Internal Customer Service - CA,300000039139652,"Chemicals, Lubricants and Non-Gen Fuels.Additives.Additives",CAD,Nisku Distribution Centre,NDC,INVENTORY,400000039139655,"TRANSFORMER, 25 KVA OH, 12470GRDY/7200/347/600Y 1PH C/W TAPS SPEC. #YECL-T-15",16340094,Goods,TEST12345678,XXXX Internal Customer Service - CA,6,xyz@discard.mail.us2.oracle.cloud.com,zzr,500,10002,00000,00000,00000,130000,00000,00,6,500000039139655,100
```

I want to write XSLT transformation to group it based on interface source code, requisitionbuname, followed by looping through InterfaceHeaderKey. Pls. suggest

Comment: It seems like this questions is incomplete, please finish it

Comment: For Each interfaceSourceCode,RequisitionBUName followed by For each InterfaceHeaderKey, Loop through all lines

Comment: Please put code that you have already tried

Comment: <xsl:template match="/">
    <tns:createRequisition>
      <tns:interfaceSourceCode><xsl:value-of select="/ns0:Root-Element/ns0:Record/ns0:interfaceSourceCode"/></tns:interfaceSourceCode>
      <tns:requisitioningBUName><xsl:value-of select="/ns0:Root-Element/ns0:Record/ns0:requisitioningBUName"/><tns:purchaseRequestPayload>
        <ns2:InterfaceHeaderKey><xsl:value-of select="/ns0:Root-Element/ns0:Record/ns0:InterfaceHeaderKey"/></ns2:InterfaceHeaderKey>
        <xsl:for-each select="/ns0:Root-Element/ns0:Record">

Comment: <ns2:PurchaseRequestInputReqLineInterface><ns2:InterfaceLineKey><xsl:value-of select="ns0:InterfaceLineKey"/></ns2:InterfaceLineKey>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </tns:purchaseRequestPayload>
    </tns:createRequisition>
  </xsl:template>

Comment: Due to size limitation pasted it as 2 different sections.

Comment: XSLT works against XML. Where is your XML?

Comment: Can anyone pls. tell me if there is a way to attach a file here?

Comment: <?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<Root-Element xmlns="http://TargetNamespace.com/getftpservice">
   <Record><org>CA</org><headerkey>325</headerkey><linekey>425</linekey><item>T1</item></Record>
   <Record><org>CA</org><headerkey>325</headerkey><linekey>426</><item>T1</item></Record>   
   <Record><org>CA</org><headerkey>326</headerkey><linekey>427</linekey><item>T1</item></Record>
   <Record><org>CA</org><headerkey>326</headerkey><linekey>428</linekey><item>T1</item></Record>
</Root-Element>

Comment: <?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<Root-Element xmlns="http://TargetNamespace.com/getftpservice">
   <Record><org>CA</org><headerkey>325</headerkey><linekey>425</linekey><item>T1</item><linekey>426</linekey><item>T1</item></Record>   
   <Record><org>CA</org><headerkey>326</headerkey><linekey>427</linekey><item>T1</item><linekey>428</linekey><item>T1</item></Record>
</Root-Element>

Comment: Expected output is

Comment: <?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<Root-Element xmlns="http://TargetNamespace.com/getftpservice">
   <Record><org>CA</org><headerkey>325</headerkey><linekey>425</linekey><item>T1</item><linekey>426</linekey><item>T1</item></Record>   
   <Record><org>CA</org><headerkey>326</headerkey><linekey>427</linekey><item>T1</item><linekey>428</linekey><item>T1</item></Record>
</Root-Element>

Comment: @Ram sorry you're obviously new to this game and you're really struggling. Don't add information to your question in comments, add it by editing the question. This has become such a mess that you're probably better off starting from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

consider using for-each-group xslt 2.0 construct.....

```
 <xsl:for-each-group select="//put your parent tag here let say interfaceSourceCode" group-by="//put your element">

      <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group().. if next grouping element is at same level or change accordingly" group-by="..put second grouping element let say requisitioningBUName and so on">

            <xsl:for-each select="//element  let say InterfaceHeaderKey">
              .....values go here
            </xsl:for-each>

      </xsl:for-each-group>

  </xsl:for-each-group>
```